# IE8 css: no background image, or float:right

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

[This website](http://www.piedmontpool.com/) uses a child theme of Twenty Twelve, and displays fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Internet Explorer 10.

However, in Internet Explorer 8, it [degrades](http://i112.photobucket.com/albums/n180/SRD001/screenshots/ie8.png):

`<div id="site" class="page">` is not displaying its background image, and `<h1 class="site-title">` is not floating right.

How do I get IE8 to display the background image, and float the h1 to the right?

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: The [exact duplicate](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94866/twenty-twelve-in-internet-explorer-8) of this you asked in WPSE was closed.  Please try and ask an actual question.

Comment: Well.. I tried with internet explorer.. But it seems working correctly here... Should it be IE8 fixed or 8.1 can work..?

Comment: IE8.0.  Try comparing what you see to what you see in Chrome, Firefox, or Opera.

Comment: @Steve I've tried to check your page in Internet Explorer 9 a few days ago, and it's working properly. How can I help you if it's working?

Comment: @Servant: The question states IE8 is the problem.

Comment: Random comment... how can we have a bounty of 50 rep when he only has 42?   Edit: NVM.. this was posted before he got nuked for this question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS to style those two elements was inside CSS media queries, which IE8 does not support.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't read the HTML5 tags correctly, you have to help him with various scripts that you can find easily online.

Try to add this script in the head of your pages:

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]> 
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"> 
    </script> 
  <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set

```
position: absolute;
float:right;
right: 100px; /**/
```

for floating h1 tag.